# How to call a Python function from Rust?

Tags: python, rust, cpython

I have a function defined in a python module:

```
def myfunc(arg1, arg2):
    print(arg1, arg2)
```

I'm trying to call it from Rust using cpython:

```
use cpython::{Python, PyResult, PyObject, PyTuple, ObjectProtocol};
use std::any::Any;

fn call(module: &str, func: &str, args: &[Box<&dyn Any>]) -> PyResult<PyObject> {
    let gil = Python::acquire_gil();
    let py = gil.python();
    let module = py.import(module)?;
    let func = module.get(py, func)?;
    let args = PyTuple::new(py, args);
    func.call(py, args, None)
}

fn main() {
    call("mymodule", "myfunc", &[Box::new(&3), Box::new(&"foo".to_string())]).unwrap();
}
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
let args = PyTuple::new(py, args);
   |                ------------     ^^^^ expected `&[PyObject]`, found `&[Box<&dyn Any>]`
   |                |
   |                arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected reference `&[cpython::PyObject]`
              found reference `&[Box<&(dyn std::any::Any + 'static)>]``
```

Seems that I have to provide a slice of `PyObject`s , but I couldn't figure out from the docs how I can build it from the arguments I want to pass.

Comment: You can't turn a `&dyn Any` into a `PyObject` cause it might be a type with no Python representation, or are you looking for [`ToPyObject::to_py_object`](https://docs.rs/cpython/latest/cpython/trait.ToPyObject.html#tymethod.to_py_object)?